# Показ элемента с картинкой по категории

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, изображения

У меня есть галерея с картинками и список с категориями (`ul`-список). Как можно реализовать показ конкретных картинок при нажатии на конкретную категорию? И, соответственно, чтобы другие картинки скрывались.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/826549/256824

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы не приложили ваш текущий код и указали только тэг `javascript`, предположу, что вам нужно на чистом js. Решение:

```js
var li_items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var gallery_items = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item');

for (i = 0; i < li_items.length; i++) {
  li_items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var category_id = this.getAttribute('data-category');
    for (j = 0; j < gallery_items.length; j++) {
      if (gallery_items[j].getAttribute('data-category') !== category_id) {
        gallery_items[j].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        gallery_items[j].style.display = "block"; // или inline или другое, смотря как у вас в вёрстке
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
Выберите категорию:
<ul>
  <li data-category="1">Категория 1</li>
  <li data-category="2">Категория 2</li>
  <li data-category="3">Категория 3</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="1">Картинка 1</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="2">Картинка 2</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="3">Картинка 3</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="1">Картинка 4</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="2">Картинка 5</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="2">Картинка 6</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="1">Картинка 7</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="2">Картинка 8</div>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-category="3">Картинка 9</div>
</div>
```

Внутри каждого `div.gallery-item` и будет `<img>`, или сам `<img>` будет иметь этот класс.

Comment: есл таких элементов будет 1миллион, тоже будете `for`'ом перебирать?)

Comment: @meine Я бы не стала выводить на одной странице галерею в миллион картинок, это как минимум безжалостно по отношению к пользователю :) И я бы использовала какую-то либу, например, jQuery. Но раз автор вопроса не указал конкретную либу в тэгах или теле вопроса, то имеем, что имеем. Если у вас есть альтернативное решение на чистом JS, пожалуйста, разместите его в ответе или комментарии.

Comment: Пожалуйста, воздержитесь отвечать на низкокачественные вопросы, где задача топикастера  не совсемм понятна. Вопрос будет повидимому скоро закрыт и будет жалко времени потраченого на ответ.

Comment: @РустамГимранов Верно. Подняла выше

Comment: @РустамГимранов, не имеет смысла отвечать на вопрос. т.к. он будет закрыт. Читайте комментарий выше.

Comment: Очень благодарен за ответ! спасибо большое!